# ActiveX Control to view outlook msg file in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, outlook, activex, msg

I am using C# Winform in .NET 3.5 in an application. I looking for a third party ActiveX control, which can show *.msg file in the viewer.

Is anybody aware, such kind of viewer, which will support this.

Thanks,
Nizam.

Comment: Could anybody kind enough to help me out.

Comment: Have you found something that does this ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2007, you can use the Namespace.OpenSharedItem method.

There is no corresponding method in the Outlook object model for earlier versions. You would need to use either shellexecute or Redemption. (Namespace.CreateItemFromTemplate only creates an unsent copy of a message.)

I didn't find anything in VSTS that can supply your demand.